# Text Block Background CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

`I` `want` `to` `know` `how` `to` `create` `a` `text` `block` `like` `this` `sentence` `in` `css.`

In the example above, each word has background of black transparancy. How to do this in CSS?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Maybe inspecting the element in the above question using Dev Tools would help :)

Comment: I use old chrome, there is no inspect elements tool in the browser. :(

Comment: Just add `display: inline-block`.

Comment: @Harry Thanks for the fiddle. But it's so complicated. Is there an easy way? In the fiddle you gave to me we have to set the style to each word. I want it to set automatically to all words.

Comment: @inandout: You can use JS and Regex like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/C3Y2V/1/) to auto create spans for every word.

Comment: It's impossible to me to create a span in each words. It's kind of wasting of time, isn't it?

Comment: @Harry please post it as an answer. :)

Comment: @lkmhr: I have a feeling that this is a duplicate question mate. Searching for the original one to link. Actually the JS I used in that answer was originally picked up from that old SO question only.

Comment: @Harry can you give me the link to the duplicate question, please?

Comment: @inandout: Maybe I am now searching with the wrong keywords but I am not able to find that. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463741/coloring-a-single-word-with-css) is the closest one that I could find and hence adding my solution as an answer. *Note:* I am removing the older fiddle comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by wrapping each word of the content inside a `<span>` tag and then assigning styles to it. Adding a `<span>` for each word can be automatically achieved using 
the below Javascript.

**Javascript:**

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]; // using [0] since demo has only one div
var txt = el.textContent; // getting the text content of the div
el.innerHTML = txt.replace(/\S+/g, function (word) { // using innerHTML to set the text because it now has an HTML tag
    return "<span>" + word + "</span>"; // wrapping each word within a span
});
```

**Note:** The above is just a simple example written with the assumption that the `div` has no child tags. If they have child tags then the script would need to be modified.

**CSS:** (for styling the span)

```
span{
    background-color: #AAA; /* this is a solid color, for transparency use the approach mentioned by Ali in his answer.
    padding: 4px;
}
```

```js
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
var txt = el.textContent;
el.innerHTML = txt.replace(/\S+/g, function(word) {
  return "<span>" + word + "</span>";
});
```

```css
span {
  background-color: #AAA;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div>I want to know how to create a text block like this sentence in css.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The above mentioned word have

```
background-color:#eee;
```

but you can make any color transparent with

```
background-color: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.48);
```

where fourth argument is for the transparency of color 0-1.

Comment: he is asking to make it for each word and NOT for whitespace.

Comment: Thanks. But it creates a background color for all the block. I want it only to each words.

Comment: if you want this for every word you will have to wrap every word in a span and then applly style on that

Comment: @Ali But I want it automatically without have to set the style on each words.